# How do I double-buffer renders to a JPanel?

Tags: java, rendering, swing, double-buffering

I'm trying to make a little breakout game with Java and Swing. The only issue so far is that drawing on the `JPanel` causes lots of flickering!

The relevant code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Breakout");
JPanel gameField = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();

private void gameLoop() {
    while(running) {
        update();
        render((Graphics2D) gameField.getGraphics());
    }
}

private void render(Graphics2D g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, gameField.getWidth(), gameField.getHeight());
    for (GameObject o : objects) {
        o.draw(g);
    }
}
```

I've looked into manually double buffering (e.g. by making an offscreen `Image`, drawing on it, then doing `g.drawImage(offscreen)`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [BufferStrategy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html), it's the preferred way to use multibuffering for java 2d, - and it works like a charm. Searching google for examples on how to use it should be straightforward :)